# Monaco Diff Overview not expanding when the height of the container overflows

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, difference, git-diff, monaco-editor

Whenever the total size of the rendered editor exceeds the height of the outlet container, the Diff Overview panel remains the same (as shown in below image)
[image]

As opposed to fitting the entire diff overview panel with in the outlet (as shown below).
[image]

The above sample is from https://www.diffchecker.com/.

Is there anyway to get the expected behaviour as shown in 2nd image in monaco diff editor?